# Array of NSStrings size 100

Tags: objective-c

Working on a app that needs to have an array of NSStrings as a board. First I need a method to initialize the NSArray of size 100 and then build methods that add random chutes and ladders across the board. The makeChutes/ladders methods will take the parameters of how many spaces to be moved. The problem I'm having is just initializing the array of NSStrings, I know I can use a non-mutable NSArray with mutable objects but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

Basically I want to initialize this:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", nil]
```

But with 100 strings and in the form of a method like so:

```
    -(id)initBoard{
        for(int i =0; i<100;i++){
            _board[i] = @"| |";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue/question?

Comment: How can I initialize an array of 100 strings?

Comment: Is there a reason you're returning `id` rather than `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` ? (assuming a missing initialisation of `_board` and `return _board;` at the end)

Comment: I have to agree with @RichTolley's comment and would also add that if _board is a property on your class, you wouldn't even need a return type and just change it to void. Unless its your class's -init method which should return self at the end

Comment: Are you trying to make your _board array to have a enumerating array from 1 to 100 or a array of 100 "| |" ?

Comment: @JustinSmith17, how about `NSMutableArray *_myArray = [NSMutableArray array]; for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) [_myArray addObject:@""];`...?

Comment: Ok, so I should make my initBoard method void and my printBoard method return self?

Comment: @iNaiuY, sorry I left out other details of the assignment. I'll update the question so it reflects what my final output should be.

Comment: alright @JustinSmith17 updated my response, should work for you now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
-(id)initBoard
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        [mutableArray addObject:@"| |"];
    }
    _board = mutableArray;
}
```

Comment: Fixed comparison on the for loop.